# Get last row in table field for loop

Tags: templating, forloop, table-field

How can I determine if the row being returned from a table field in a for loop is the last row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig's `for` loop exposes a `loop` variable with a number of useful properties, including `last`:

```
{% for row in table %}
    ...
    {% if loop.last %}
        // Do stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

See [the official Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) for more information on the `loop` variable and its properties (first, last, index etc).

Answer (score 3):

In any for loop you can use the `loop` variable that twig gives you.

For example:

```
{% for row in myTable %}
  {% if loop.last %}
    This is the last row
  {% else %}
    This is anything but the last row
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

More information on the loop variable can be found in the [twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).